# DynamoDB tables uses more Read/Write capacity than expected

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto, bandwidth

Background: I have a DynamoDB table which I interact exclusively with a DAO class. This DAO class logs metrics on the number of calls to insert/update/delete operations to the boto library.

I noticed that the # of operations I logged in my code do correlate with the consumed read/write capacity on AWS monitoring but the AWS measurements on consumption are 2 - 15 times the # of operations I logged in my code.

I know for a fact that the only other process interacting with the table is my manual queries on the AWS UI (which is insignificant in capacity consumption). I also know that the size of each item is < 1 KB, which would mean each call should only consume 1 read.

I use strong consistent reads so I do not enjoy the 2x benefit of eventual consistent reads.

I am aware that boto auto-retries at most 10 times when throttled but my throttling threshold is seldomly reached to trigger such a problem.

With that said, I wonder if anyone knows of any factor that may cause such a discrepency in # of calls to boto w.r.t. the actual consume capacities.

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not sure of the support with the boto AWS SDK, in other languages it is possible to ask DynamoDB to return the capacity that was consumed as part of each request.  It sounds like you are logging actual requests and not this metric from the API itself.  The values returned by the API should accurately reflect what is consumed.

One possible source for this discrepancy is if you are doing query/scan requests where you are performing server side filtering.  DynamoDB will consume the capacity for all of the records scanned and not just those returned.

Another possible cause of a discrepancy are the actual metrics you are viewing in the AWS console.  If you are viewing the CloudWatch metrics directly make sure you are looking at the appropriate SUM or AVERAGE value depending on what metric you are interested in.  If you are viewing the metrics in the DynamoDB console the interval you are looking at can dramatically affect the graph (ex: short spikes that appear in a 5 minute interval would be smoothed out in a 1 hour interval).